# Text gets pushed down when resizing and gets pushed out of its container. Why is this happening?

Tags: html, css

I just cannot figure out why, when I resize the window, that the text gets pushed down, out of its container (mainImage). What I would like for it to do is basically just keep the background image where it is on the screen and have the text scroll over it. I have googled constantly to no avail and I am so frustrated I just had to ask in my own way. I apologize if this has already been explained somewhere else but I just cannot find it. If somebody can shed some light on the subject for me I would really appreciate it.

```css
html{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

#name{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 10%;
  /* border: 1px solid white; */
  width: 270px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;

}

#nav{
  top: 7%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

ul{
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

li{
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}


#cover{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)); */
}

#mainImage{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('IMG_0063.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/*
#footer{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
} */

h3{
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  color: white;
  /* border: 1px solid green; */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

p{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 70%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 930px) {
  #nav{
    top: 15%;
    /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
    text-align: center;
  }

  #name{
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  ul{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
    /* border: 1px solid red; */
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin|Arvo|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Gallery</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="cover"></div>
    <div id="mainImage">
      <div id="name">Name</div>
      <h3>Welcome</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
         elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
         aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
         laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
         reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
         sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- <div id="footer"></div> -->





  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `height` of `100%` on everything from `#mainImage` and up. While this (in theory) would cause these elements to occupy the full page, the problem is that you have more content than can be displayed on a single page, causing scrolling.

Assuming you **want** scrolling content, and only want to ensure that the background and text is visible, what you'll need to do is remove the `height: 100%` from `#mainImage`. This will shift the `<p>` tags **up** the page. To counteract this, you'll want to give them a `position: absolute`, and a `left` of `15%` (`(100% - 70%) / 2)`).

This will fix everything for desktop views, though will still have the grey background not expanding on mobile views. The final thing you'll want to correct is shifting all of the `background` rules from `#mainImage` and `#cover` to `body`. Note that the `opacity` will now affect the **text**, so if you want a grey background, you should specify that instead of using `opacity`.

This can all be seen in the following:

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: url('IMG_0063.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)); */
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}

#name {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 10%;
  /* border: 1px solid white; */
  width: 270px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

#nav {
  top: 7%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

ul {
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

#cover {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#mainImage {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}


/*
#footer{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
} */

h3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  color: white;
  /* border: 1px solid green; */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 70%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 930px) {
  #nav {
    top: 15%;
    /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
    text-align: center;
  }
  #name {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
    /* border: 1px solid red; */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin|Arvo|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Gallery</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="cover"></div>
  <div id="mainImage">
    <div id="name">Name</div>
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- <div id="footer"></div> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!